# How can I change a button when I select a item in a flatlist

Tags: javascript, react-native

I saw some questions about it here on SO, but none of them work for me.

So my problem is when I click on the button "Add Friend" all of the buttons change to "remove", and I want to change only the button that I click

[Normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R63r6.png)

[When I click in any button, all of them change to "remove"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFqsb.png)

My Code is:

```
export default class Friends extends Component {
  state = {
    visible: false,
    userInfo: null,
    requested: null
  }

buttonAdd() {
  if (this.state.requested === null) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.add]} onPress={() => this.setState({ requested: true })}>
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Add Friend</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.remove]}>
          <Text style={{ color: "#050505", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Remove</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  } else if (this.state.requested === true) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.remove, styles.removeBig]} onPress={() => this.setState({ requested: false })} >
          <Text style={{ color: "#050505", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Remove</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  } else {
    return (
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.add]} onPress={() => this.setState({ requested: true })}>
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Add Friend</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.remove]}>
          <Text style={{ color: "#050505", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Remove</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    )
  }
}



render() {
  const inform = this.props.info
  return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={inform}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        ListHeaderComponent={this.topComponents()} //ignore this //with the ListHeaderComponent the components will not repeat  
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <View style={styles.peopleContainer}>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({ visible: true, userInfo: item })}>               <Image source={item.photo} style={styles.photo} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={styles.geralContent}>
              <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
              {this.buttonAdd()}
            </View>
          </View>
        )}
      />
    </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Sorry about the huge code.

Comment: All the items currently sharing same state. You have to either maintain separate state for each item or manage a array in your Friends class state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be several approaches to handle this. This is just my approach to handle this specific issue.

Currently, all of the items sharing the same state. That means if any of the items update the component state, it will affect all the items of the FlatList. To overcome this problem we need to refactor the code so every item has its own state. Here is a snippet of how to do that and fix the problem

```
const FriendItem = ({ item, onPressPhoto }) => {
  const [requested, setRequested] = React.useState(false)
  return (
    <View style={styles.peopleContainer}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPressPhoto({ visible: true, userInfo: item })}>
        <Image source={item.photo} style={styles.photo} />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.geralContent}>
        <Text style={styles.name}>{item.name}</Text>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          {!requested ?
            <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.add]} onPress={() => setRequested(true)}>
              <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Add Friend</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            :
            null
          }
          <TouchableOpacity style={[styles.button, styles.remove]}>
            <Text style={{ color: "#050505", fontWeight: "bold" }}>Remove</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>

  )
}

export default class Friends extends Component {
  state = {
    visible: false,
    userInfo: null,
  }
  onPressPhoto = ({ visible, userInfo }) => {
    //write your logic here to handle on click
  }
  render() {
    const inform = this.props.info
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
          data={inform}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.topComponents()} //ignore this //with the ListHeaderComponent the components will not repeat  
          renderItem={({ item }) => <FriendItem item={item} onPressPhoto={this.onPressPhoto} />}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```